# Excel MAC VBA Dropdown

Tags: excel, vba, macos

on MAC OFFICE 2011 I am trying to get this working: http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal10.html

There is a sample file that you can download: http://www.contextures.com/DataValCombobox.zip

But when I open the worksheet and click on a cell I get the following error:

"Method or data member not found"

```
Set cboTemp = ws.OLEObjects("TempCombo")
  On Error Resume Next
If cboTemp.Visible = True Then
  With cboTemp
    .Top = 10
    .Left = 10
    .ListFillRange = ""
    .LinkedCell = ""
    .Visible = False
    .Value = "" <<<- HIGHLIGHTED
  End With
End If
```

The debugger highlights the .value as indicated above.

What is the cause of this and can it be fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because `.Value` isn't a property of the ComboBox.

[Here is the list of properties you can use.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.controls.combobox_properties.aspx)

You are probably looking for

```
.SelectedValue
```

or Depending on which column you have the Rowsource bound.

```
.SelectedIndex
```

You can also use

```
.Text
```